# Export to vector graphics fails with large number of data-points

Tags: matlab, vector, graphics

I want to export some MATLAB-plots as vector-graphics for presentations. In the most cases, using `print`-command, for example:

```
set(0,'defaultAxesTickLabelInterpreter','Latex')
set(0,'defaultTextInterpreter','Latex')

t=linspace(0,6,6000);
s=sin(t);

figure
for spl=1:16
    subplot(4,4,spl);
    plot(t,s,'k')
end

print('Sinetest','-dpdf');
```

but as soon as the number of data-points (or the expected file size) turns too big, for example use `t=linspace(0,6,7000);` the method fails: instead of a scalable vector graphic, an ugly pixel-monster is saved in the .pdf-file. I've tried to use other file-formats, for exampl .emf, .eps, .svg (svg is what I need actually) instead of .pdf, but it's always the same problem. Reducing the number of data points works in this example, but not in general for me.

Is there any option or work around?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to specify that the [`painter` renderer](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html#inputarg_renderer) should be used:

```
print('Sinetest','-dpdf', '-painters');
```

> If you save to a vector graphics file and if the figure `RendererMode`
>   property is set to `'auto'`, then print automatically attempts to use
>   the Painters renderer. If you want to ensure that your output format
>   is a true vector graphics file, then specify the Painters renderer.

Note that this may result in long rendering times as mentioned in the docs:

> Sometimes, saving a file with the '-painters' option can cause longer
>   rendering times [...]